# Client side infinite looping

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm trying to implement a method to check if the server is still up. I'm using sockets to communicate between server and client. My aim is to print a newline character to the server to test whether it is still up, if it isn't an IOException will be thrown and the client will enter a reconnection process.

My problem is after I've stopped the server in terminal, my client enters an infinite loop of printing "Response from server:" when it should not.

Code on client side:

```
private static void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;
    try{
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contentSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println("Response from server:");
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(userInput);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong (5)");
    }
}

private static void testConenction( Socket socket ) throws IOException{
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong (355)");
    }
}

    try{
    //Connection stuff  
        while( true ){
            try{
                testConenction(contentSocket);
                readResponse();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Something went wrong (327)");
                closeSocket(contentSocket);
                System.out.println("Trying to re-establish connection");
                reconnect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks about right,

```
    while( true ){
        try{
            testConenction(contentSocket);
            readResponse();
```

Here readResponse() is set in a loop (with no end in sight). Instead, maybe include a wait / sleep and try another way.

If you're getting "Response from server:", maybe check if userInput is null / empty, and exit.

Comment: technically there is no user input, its a syndication server with clients

Comment: My mistake, I should have been more clear, check if this user input is null :

private static void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;

Comment: I see what you mean now, but if userInput were to be null I should hit Exception (5). readResponse() main function is to retrieve a HTTP 200

Comment: Maybe not, you can do a quick check to see, place an if (userInput == null) condition after this while loop: while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null). Then print either a yes or no, this may elaborate if it is a good idea to catch the condition of userInput being null or not.

Comment: Point being, if it were *not* null, then you should it being printed from: System.out.println(userInput);. I have a suspicion that it is

Comment: Well I have to say, you found a bug that hadn't even happened yet. Everyone’s help was very appreciated, but I had a brain fart. I was compiling and not running the new .class file. Sorry everyone :-)

Comment: Lol no problem, happens to all of us

Answer (score 0):

Once the connection has been established a boolean flag should be set to true which would denote that the connection to the server has been established. If the flag is found to be true then we will not test the connection any longer.

Also I was wondering that if ur catching IOException in testConenction method then the Exception will not get propagated to the calling method.

Comment: By this you mean swap while(true) with say, while(connected), where connected is a boolean?

Comment: Yes. I think its important to keep an indicator to understand that the connection one established once. Only thats how we can distinguish a fresh new connection and the disconnection.

Comment: After implementing the boolean, sadly I still get the same result.

Comment: Just checking...Initially if u set the value like this : static boolean isConnected = false; while( true && !isConnected){
            try{
                testConenction(contentSocket);   ....                Does this logic give u an error??

Answer (score 0):

You catch the exceptions in the two methods so that the exception 327 cannot be thrown and reconnect is never called.

You don't have to check if you get an answer, it is enough to send something. The TCP-Protocol (used by sockets) will ensure that the server receives the packet, if not it will throw an exception.